# how to roll back TFS(Team Foundation server) work space to previous version

Tags: tfs

I had a work space which consists of last month's version of the solution by mistake I took full latest instead of taking specific version, can I roll back to last month's version without using changeset.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't shelve or check in your code, you can't. A workspace is **local**. You should not leave changes uncommitted for a long time -- I generally recommend checking code in at least once a day, preferably much more frequently.

If you're working on a long-running change, use branches to isolate work in progress.

Comment: Or preferable use feature toggles 